# Where are Magento URL rewrites stored?

Tags: url-rewrite, magento-1.7

I would like to restore my URL rewrites file to an earlier time before I made changes but I don't to do a full database restore if it's not necessary. Is there a certain file I can restore instead?

The problem is a emptied my core_url_rewrites table and lost a lot of my rewrites when I reindexed.

Comment: if you do not have a database backup then I doubt you will be able to restore this information.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the table **core_url_rewrite** which you can restore.

If you are just interested in your custom rewrites entries then you can use restore **core_url_rewrite** as **temp_core_url_rewrite** and run the following command to get your custom URLs restored -:

```
INSERT INTO core_url_rewrite SELECT * FROM temp_core_url_rewrite WHERE is_system=0
```

Hope it helps

Cheers
S